# What is the Handled filter in Chrome DevTools used for?

Tags: javascript, console, filtering, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome DevTools has several useful filters to limit the logging: `Errors`, `Warnings`, `Info` etc.

The last filter is called `Handled`, and I have yet to find out what that is used for. The is no `console.handle()` or similar. Googling hasn't provided an answer.

For what and how do I use the `Handled` filter?

Comment: Seems to relate to handled exceptions, but I'm struggling to see how.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This filter is for exceptions handled inside of a promise. The filter was added to the UI with [this patch](https://codereview.chromium.org/1095943002). Included [test](https://codereview.chromium.org/1095943002/patch/240001/250005) and linked [ticket](http://crbug.com/393913) reveal what this feature is all about.

---

If we create a promise and reject it like so:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('ooops'))
```

error message will be immediately printed to the console:

[image: uncaught error in promise]

However, rejection can be handled later on:

```
p.catch(e => {})
```

causing previous error message to change state:

[image: handled error]

"*Uncaught (in promise) ooops*" becomes a "*handled promise rejection*". Since it's not considered an error anymore it will not show up when the "*Errors*" filter is active. It will show up though, when the new "*Handled*" filter is active.

[image: revoked error not visible when "errors" filter is active]

[image: revoked error visible when "Handled" filter is active]